# Design suggestion for a register page via smartcard

Tags: forms, gui-design, interaction-design, user-behavior

Context

1. Developing a Login/Registration page
2. Security is very important

To reduce code complexity, I want to use just one controller and FXML page.
I want to create a form to register three users at once. Below you see an example to get a better picture what I am looking for.

Each user need to enter their credentials that are getting saved via smartcard. This would mean that one user after the other would need to enter their credentials and each user has its own smartcard.

What would be the most elegant way to solve this from technical and additonally user point of view.

Please no comments about layout, this is still in progress.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you might try:

1. You should give the form a reasonable title, suitable for the process. Like “Users creation” or “Smart-card users initialization” (those are my speculations, make it clear and compact)
2. Form would be cleaner without the indent on every line that is not a header. Just make group headers bold to stand out.
3. Grouping is good, but you could go further. Get rid of repetitions and keep one “password” word in a group. Rewrite “repeat password” as a “repeat” caption near the field, or inside of it.
4. Repeating a password isn't a user-friendly act. And you should design a validation state for the fields. I would suggest to open symbols to check the password visually (maybe with a global switch named “show passwords”). I suppose, it won't be used in a public environment.
5. Align the submit button with something else on a screen.
6. One form — one button. If you want to create users separately, there should be a distinction between separate forms. It totally depends on a process you have under the hood. So get restrictions from it and make the UI that doesn't conflict with them.

Comment: I created the form above just for visualization of my question. Do you think it is better to create for each user an own page. User 1 creates his credentials, then a next page shows up for the next user? Yes, the application is not for public usage.... Security is very important.

Comment: It depends on the workflow and backend restrictions. I don't know anything about smartcards and their use cases. Is it possible to create users separately? If yes, you could make three forms. Are users 2 and 3 optional? Can I add them later? If I can, how would I see users that are already created on a smartcard. How the interface would prevent data loss if users are only rewritable in one scope (previous users might be overwritten)? Can I edit them? And after all, what is the reason to have three users? Anwsering questions like that would give you the answer on how to organize the form(s).